# JSON Schema object to Typescript Type on the fly

Tags: typescript, jsonschema

I basically want to do something like that:

```js
const jsonSchema = {...} as const;

type SchemaType = JsonSchemaToType<typeof jsonSchema>;
```

so that I can do:

```
export default (input: SchemaType) => {
   validate(input, jsonSchema)
   ...
}
```

so have schema validation as well as typescript typing based on the same schema, ideally on the fly.

It should basically do the same as this web tool: https://transform.tools/json-schema-to-typescript
but directly in my code.

If it is not possible in plain typescript, a plugin for webpack would help as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found a library that actually does the job: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-schema-to-ts

```
import type { FromSchema } from "json-schema-to-ts";
const jsonSchema = {...} as const;

type SchemaType = FromSchema<typeof jsonSchema>;

export default (input: SchemaType) => {
   validate(input, jsonSchema)
   ...
}
```

Comment: This is actually a fantastic package. You can combine it with the `aws-lambda` event like this: 
```import { APIGatewayEvent } from "aws-lambda";
import homepageSubmitSchema from "./schemas/homepageSubmitSchema";

type Event = APIGatewayEvent & FromSchema<typeof homepageSubmitSchema>;```